# android NDK HOWTO get stack trace without backtrace

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, arm

I want to get stack trace when my progrom crash in my .so library, in fact, i call the interface in .so from JNI.

And I follow a old question, but not worked.
All I get in the dumpBacktrace is the signal handler itself.
Here's [the link of old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8115192/android-ndk-getting-the-backtrace).

platform: arm, ndk-version: android-ndk-r10d

Comment: What exactly do you want to get? The terms "stacktrace" and "backtrace" are often used interchangeably. Do you want to get a stack *dump*? Or a *trace* of all functions in the *call stack*?

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg ， Yes,  i wanna get a trace of all functions in the call stack. There is no backtrace() in ndk.

Comment: After reading your question a little more thoroughly I have another couple of questions. Do you catch crashes (such as segmentation fault) using a signal handler (i.e. you install a handler for `SIGSEGV`)? Then you can't rely on the call stack because signal handlers are special cases and are called directly from the kernel. I do not personally know how to get a call trace in such a case, but the original (non-signal handler) stack should be available to get somehow from the kernel I think.

Answer (score 0):

you should definitely check out coffecatch: https://github.com/xroche/coffeecatch