# Crashing when trying to do __android_log_print getting backtrace on samsung s8+

Tags: android, c++, logging, backtrace, samsung-galaxy

I'm trying to get a the backtrace log when my c++ application got different signals.

I've implement it the following solution:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35585744/1894850

But I've got the following problem:

When I raise the signal `(SIGSEGV)` I can catch it, but when I try to log using the function `__android_log_print` the application crashes.
I've tried the same code on a `Pixel C`, and it logged properly, but when I'm using a Samsung s8+ the same code crashes without any trace.

Is there any meaning for this?