# How to use CallStack (in CallStack.tpp) in a executable on android platform?

Tags: android, linux, build, stack-trace, callstack

A question from https://stackoverflow.com/a/11467040/1442443

**my final target is to dump user space stack.**

I try to build a cpp file as below to a **executable** on android platform. Therefore, by calling tryToGetStack(), I can get call stack of my executable in run time.

```
#include <utils/CallStack.h>
namespace android
{
    extern "C" void tryToGetStack()
    {
        CallStack stack;
        stack.update();
        stack.dump("");
    }
}
```

and add lib setting to to Android.mak since CallStack.tpp is in libutils

> LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES += libutils

but I always get error with message:

> error: undefined reference to 'android::CallStack::CallStack()'
>
> error: undefined reference to 'android::CallStack::update(int, int)'
>
> ...

It seems the executable resolve the symbols at link time rather than load the .so file in runtime?
Do I missing something or there is some limit in Android build system?

I know it is a simple question, but I really need help...

**update1**

I try to add the code to another **executable**.  The result is same...  Does anyone knows the rule of android build system?

**update2**

There are some key words in my console **"target StaticExecutable: ..."**, I think is is the answer.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_executable

Comment: FYI it looks like CallStack is now provided in `libutilscallstack` on android-p.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

my final target is to **dump user space stack**.

after google so many information from internet, I found there are 4 ways:

1. **ptrace**： http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ptrace

   It is really hard to use ptrace, and we need to stop the thread before using ptrace to attach
2. **_unwind_backtrace**: the way used by CallStack (CallStack class in CallStack.cpp)

   example: http://git.stlinux.com/?p=stm/uclibc.git;a=blob;f=libubacktrace/sysdeps/sh/backtrace.c;h=18b91b1bb3fa26344a521927c631553a410fcf56;hb=d6a3d9ece5922a337800a8e2ed4db7e226f9ccb3

   It is work with a drawback: if you use it as the thread is processing signal, it would dump signal stack rather than dump thread stack

   The same problen: [How to get fullstacktrace using _Unwind_Backtrace on SIGSEGV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6254058/how-to-get-fullstacktrace-using-unwind-backtrace-on-sigsegv)
3. **backtrace**: http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Backtraces.html

   a GNU extension function, not be implemented in Bionic libc used by Android

   reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8295238/1442443

   reference: http://lists.puredata.info/pipermail/pd-list/2012-02/094258.html
4. **a patch to dump user space thread stack**: http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/linux/kernel/1525096

   but only be implemented in X86 architecture... orz

   I try to port it to android, no it only shows the first frame of stack since arm does not use frame pointer.

So... 2 is the answer.

However, I wonder if someone can resolve the problem : [How to get fullstacktrace using _Unwind_Backtrace on SIGSEGV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6254058/how-to-get-fullstacktrace-using-unwind-backtrace-on-sigsegv)

**update:**

if you can use cross compiler to use glic to compile your code, maybe you can use 3. backtrace !
http://communities.mentor.com/community/cs/archives/arm-gnu/msg02514.html

**update2**
a good article

http://codingrelic.geekhold.com/2009/05/pre-mortem-backtracing.html

Answer (score 2):

Since this is such an important question here is my answer that worked for me.  My code is in C so it has to call a C++ function that can access android::CallStack.

stackdump.cpp:

```
#include < utils/CallStack.h >
extern "C" void dumpCallStack( char *label)
{
   android::CallStack cs;
   cs.update();
   cs.dump(label);
}
```

my main code (foo.c):

```
void dumpCallStack(char *label);

...

dumpCallStack(\__FUNCTION__);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem once. And it is hard to interpret.

The syntax is of course correct and reasonable!

I have tried many methods but it did not work.

Finally, I got an idea that, the lib reference "LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES += libutils" should be put into a makefile generating a dynamic library rather than into a makefile generating a static library. This is the final reason.

Reference:
http://yongbingchen.github.io/blog/2013/05/09/dump-stack-in-android-native-c-code/

Answer (score 0):

I also received this error, but I added:

```
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES += libutils
```

before line of `LOCAL_MODULE := xxx` in `vm/Android.m` of three targets and added

```
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES += libcorkscrew
```

in `vm/Android.mk`

and `libdex/Android.mk`, and same for the `dexlist/Android.mk`, `dexdump/Android.mk`

After all these done, it works for me.