# Load of address X with insufficient space for an object of type 'int'

Tags: c, pointers

I am working on a school project where we use a signal handler to modify the program counter in order to skip over a division by 0. Also, the rules for the project specify that we must manually alter the program counter this way, and we cannot use any other code than what is there already. After using gdb, I am pretty certain that the program counter is consistently 156 bytes after the location of signalno, and the program actually has the correct output. It just keeps giving me a strange error.

```
stack.c:12:2: runtime error: load of address 0xffe258ac with insufficient space for an object of type 'int'
0xffe258ac: note: pointer points here
  00 00 00 00 16 25 65 56  23 00 00 00 82 02 01 00  20 5f e2 ff 2b 00 00 00  50 5b e2 ff 00 00 00 00
              ^ 
p1: 0xffe25810, p2: 0xffe258ac, v: 56652516
```

stack.c:12 points to the print statement. Here's my code:

```c
void signal_handle(int signalno) {
    printf("p1: %p, p2: %p, v: %x\n", &signalno, (&signalno) + 39, *((&signalno) + 39));
    printf("I was slain!\n");
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int x=5, y = 0, z=4;

    signal(SIGFPE, signal_handle);
    z=x/y;

    printf("I live again, z: %d\n", z);

    return 0;
}
```

The data should be a pointer to an instruction, which I thought would be a long, but casting to a long pointer did not fix anything. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting the saved instruction pointer address from a signal handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5397041/getting-the-saved-instruction-pointer-address-from-a-signal-handler)

Comment: I don't think so, there is a lot of code in there I'm not allowed to use.

Comment: You are intentionally reading from where you shouldn't. And you are using an address sanitizer to catch such problems. Why is it surprising that it tells you so?

Comment: I know this is not the correct way to build programs. I really just want to understand the error so I can get rid of the error message.

Comment: The error message is telling you that the thing you say you are required to do is in fact not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

There's ways to access and change the signal-handler-saved instruction pointer symbolically.

E.g., on x86-64 Linux, I can do:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void signal_action(int Signo, siginfo_t *Info, void *Uc);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int x=5, y = 0, z=4;
    asm("" : "+r"(y)); //prevent the optimizer from statically detecting a divide by zero

    //register sigaction with extra context info
    struct sigaction sa; sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
    sa.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
    sa.sa_sigaction = &signal_action;
    sigaction(SIGFPE, &sa, NULL);

    z=x/y;

    printf("I live again, z: %d\n", z);

    return 0;
}

//access and change the signal-handler-saved instruction-pointer
//(platform dependent)
#include <sys/ucontext.h>
void signal_action(int Signo, siginfo_t *Info, void *Uc){
    ucontext_t *uc = Uc;
    enum { IDIV_SIZE = 2 };
    uc->uc_mcontext.gregs[REG_RIP] += IDIV_SIZE;
}
```

A more portable way could be to have the signal handler `siglongjmp` to a previously `sigsetjmp`'d `sigjmp_buf`.

Comment: These might work, but unfortunately the assignment instructions do not allow us to use any of this. We are required to use the method shown in my question. Thanks anyway!